# How can i delete a customer under sales in openerp

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, openerp-7

I am a newbie to openerp. I have a customer called 'flipflop' under sales.
Related to this customer i have one sale which is in sales order status.
When i try to delete this customer i am getting a warning like below,

```
Integrity Error

The operation cannot be completed, probably due to the following:
- deletion: you may be trying to delete a record while other records still reference it
- creation/update: a mandatory field is not correctly set

[object with reference: Users - res.users]
```

So what i did is i went to sales orders and tried to delete the particular sale which is related to this customer , but in here also i am getting a warning like below,

```
Invalid Action!

In order to delete a confirmed sales order, you must cancel it.
To do so, you must first cancel related picking for delivery orders.
```

So where i can find these delivery orders and how can i cancel it?
Am i doing in the correct way?
Is there any other way that i can delete this customer and its related sales.

Note:I wouldn't like to go into the database and delete it.

Answer (score 1):

When you `Confirm` the `Sale Order`, `the Procurement` and `Delivery Order` is made. Based on `Product Configuration`, `Manufacture Order` or `Purchase Order` is generate when you click on **Run the Procurement**. Now Follow the below steps.

- **Warehouse** => Receive/Deliver By Orders => Delivery Order => Find your SO their. Source Document is your SO name. And Cancel that Delivery.
- **Accounting** => Customers => Customer Invoice =>  Find your SO their. Source Document is your SO name. And Cancel that Invoice. And also cancel related Journal Entry also.
- **Sales** => Sale Order => find your Record and Cancel it.
- **Customer** => find your customer name and Delete it.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: In warehousing and accounting steps i don't have any option to cancel the delivery. I have only the following options available      1.Send By Mail 2. Print 3. Register Payment  4.  Refund Invoice

Comment: Than Refund Invoice and than Cancel Invoice and than delete it. :-)